# How to model VRP with splittable goods?

Tags: optaplanner

I am customizing the VRP example for our use case, but I am stuck with how to change the domain model to accommodate goods that can be split and transported by multiple vehicles. For example collecting water with tankers.

I could split up every load into discrete chunks and create a separate location for each one, but that would blow up the search space. Otherwise I have to somehow tweak the domain model to allow a location to be included in multiple routes and determine the amount to be taken. My first thought was to build the routes from `waypoint` objects, link them to the locations and apply a (suboptimal) fill until full policy, but the number of waypoints changes during optimization and adding a lot of probably unused waypoints just to have enough does not seem to be a great idea.

Currently we have to visit 100-800 locations, and we have 3-10 stops per route in average.

An example where this would be useful:

[image]

Any pointers are appreciated!